# Calculating Time difference from two varchar(2) columns

Tags: sql, oracle, date-arithmetic

I have two variables which are both `varchar(2)` and I am trying to evaluate the time difference.

```
started := 13:42:09
finished: = 13:53:51
```

Can someone advise the best way to perform this in SQL?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Good questions show some effort in trying to solve the issue. What have you tried so far? Is the issue in converting these strings to dates? Or in computing a difference between dates? Also, storing dates in strings is a very bad idea, can't you modify the tables to handle proper date columns? Also, the piece of code you posted does not work

Comment: Sorry, the DBA in Austria will not change it...[not sure why]

Comment: I have tried the below, to convert it to a time format then I need to work the time difference, FINISHED - STARTED..
select 
((To_char(orq.check_tag,'HH24')*3600)+(to_char(orq .check_tag,'MM')*60)+(to_char(orq.check_tag,'ss'))) 
+ ((to_char(orq.order_tag,'HH24')*3600)+(to_char(orq.order_tag,'MM')*60)+(to_char(orq.order_tag,'ss')))
from order_request orq where check_tag is not null

Comment: What happens when the times go over midnight to next day?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - funny how many systems forget that edge case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only is storing dates as strings a bad idea, storing times only as strings is a particularly bad idea, because it is very hard to get a diff between them.  In the query below, I resort to creating dates on a certain day, but at the start and finish times specified by your string columns.

```
select 24 * 60 *
       (to_date ('06-Jan-2010' || ' ' || finished, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') -
        to_date ('06-Jan-2010' || ' ' || started, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')) as diff_in_minutes
from dual
```

Subtracting dates in Oracle should yield the number of days between them.  Multiplying by `24*60` should yield the difference in minutes.

**Edit:**

User @Ben comments that this can be achieved without even using a date, and that the current day would be used by default.  While my current query appears to be correct, a leaner alternative would be to omit the dummy dates completely.

Comment: @Ben I would welcome you to edit my answer.  I'm not an Oracle person.

Comment: got an error message when I used this query......ORA-00932 : inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE                                                                                                           select to_date ('06-Jan-2010' || ' ' || orq.order_tag, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') -
       to_date ('06-Jan-2010' || ' ' || orq.check_tag, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') * 24 * 60 as diff_in_minutes
from order_request orq where check_tag is not null

Comment: @sbirdi Reload your page please.  I was missing a parenthesis.

Comment: @sbirdi You should find out why the DBA will not change this.

Comment: @BobC I'm not sure why, but the DBA obviously hasn't been spending enough time on SO :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen And should not the dba be doing "administration " rather than "prevention"?  Oh well. As a wise man once said "people get the systems they deserve"

Comment: Tim, thankyou very much for your help, this has done the trick...you don't know how much happy I am know,.....THANKS AGAIN...

Comment: @sbirdi - if this answer has been useful you should accept and/or upvote it. Accepted answers improve the quality of SO as a resource for future Seekers

Comment: That's what I get for commenting while compiling @Tim. As you've edited anyway I'm just gonna delete the comment.